# React-konva получение координат точек многоугольника при зуме

Tags: javascript, reactjs, konvajs

Вопрос такой. Приложение добавляет многоугольники. Каждый проходит валидацию, на предмет того, что каждый должен лежать внутри серого многоугольника и не должны пересекаться друг с другом. Приложение работает верно пока, не использую зум или драг по сцене. Проблема в getAbsoluteTransform() внутри getNewPoints. Так как при зуме отрабатывает не корректно. Использовал сначала getTransform, но потом пришлось объединить в группы ряды, а для элементов внутри групп getTransform не возвращает текущее положение. Подскажите как поправить проблему.

Ссылка на демо https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-tree-49utnt?file=/src/Editor.tsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подсчеты не правильны, так как вы сравниваете точки в разных координатных системах:

```js
checkPolygonInsidePolygon(getNewPoints(line), pointsWalls)
```

`pointsWalls` - используется как локальные координаты, в то время как `getNewPoints(line)` это обсолютные координаты (с учётом scale и смещения stage).

Нужно приводить всё в единую систему координат. Проще всего работать с локальными координатами, не обращая внимания на трансформации stage. Вариантов решения очень много. Можно передать любого родителя, например `stage` или `mainGroup`, в функцию `getAbsoluteTransform`. Тогда будут подсчитаны координаты, относительно переданного контейнера.

```js
const transform = elem.getAbsoluteTransform(mainGroup.current);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-shape-xuc7v8?file=/src/Editor.tsx:3413-3476

P.S. Лучше вообще не использовать эти методы из Konva. Вся информация о координатах и положении фигур должна находится в состоянии приложения. Из состояния можно вычислить всё необходимые данные.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ!